# C++ и многоуровневые вложенные try-catch

Tags: c++, исключения, catch, try

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
try
{
    throw _1();
}
catch (...)
{
    try
    {
        throw _2();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw _3();
    }
    throw;
}
```

Я хочу понять следующее:

1) Что именно происходит, когда случается `throw _2;`? Активное исключение (`_1`) заменяется другим (`_2`)?

2) Какое именно исключение будет проброшено дальше при вызове `throw;`?

3) Если `throw _3;` не будет, то будет ли что-нибудь проброшено дальше?

Comment: Посмотрите на [примере](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acc8cd6c04bba7aa). `throw _3` случается и вызывается `std::terminate`.

Comment: `std::terminate()` вызывается в том случае, если ловить исключение больше некому, а, допустим, это не так.

Comment: Сделаем новый [пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f788432fb22bf729) с ещё одним `try-catch` - тогда есть кому ловить. `throw _3` случается и ловится. До пустого `throw` исполнение не доходит.

Comment: 1) что такое активное исключенние? первый кэтч словит _1 и бросит _2 2) throw вызван не будет 3) да, проброшено будет _1.

Comment: throw - работает схоже как return или goto, только передаёт управление в ближайший catch именно той обвертки try-catch, где это случилось. Если в текущем методе такой обвертки нету - берется обвертка из функции которая вызвала данную, и функция функции вызвавшей данную - так сканируется весь стек-трейс до встречи try-catch. Если соответствующий try-catch не встетился - идет аварийный выход.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь нет никакой необходимости "заменять" активное исключение. Механизмы обработки исключений прекрасно "вкладываются" друг в друга. `throw _2();` выбрасывает свое, независимое исключение. Если бы это исключение не ловилось сразу внутри первого обработчика, а вылетало бы за его пределы, то исключение `_1` бы деструктировалось при выходе из обработчика, ибо его обработка завершена. А исключение `_2` летело бы дальше.

В вашем же варианте после `throw _3();`, исключение `_2` ловится вторым обработчиком и деструктируется при выходе из этого второго обработчика, а исключение `_1` деструктируется при выходе из первого обработчика - их обработка завершена. А исключение `_3` летит дальше.

Если же вы в своем коде уберете `throw _3();`, то после завершения обработки `_2` через посредство `throw;` будет перевыброшено `_1`.

В текущем состоянии кода из-за `throw _3();` управление никогда не дойдет до `throw;`

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за помощь.